# basic_string to basic_string_view Implicit Conversion... ughhh why?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, implicit-conversion, string-view

The C++ Standards Committee had an opportunity to make code safer with string_view but they opted to add implicit conversion from basic_string to basic_string_view.

So effectively, they're saying this

```
// No worries, everyone always reads the docs...
struct Foo{
      string_view sv;
      //I really want to make this constexpr
      constexpr Foo(string_view sv):sv(sv){} 
};

/* ...some Friday afternoon... */

string s{"Looks like it works"};
Foo f{s + "..."};
```

is less important than this

```
string f{"foo"};
string_view b{"bar"};
i_wonder(f == b);
//glad I didn't have to type static_cast<string_view>(f)!!
```

Please tell me that there are better reasons for an implicit conversion from basic_string to basic_string_view.

The worst part is you need string_view to take advantage of constexpr (I know, or char*...)

UPDATE: this question has been put on hold because it doesn't meet SO's guidelines. Fair enough. I think that this is something that needs to be highlighted. I think this is **implicit** conversion is a step backwards. I'm starting to see people (even very experienced people) write dangling-pointers because of this like it's the 90's.

What are the best practices for using string_view specifically WRT the risk of implicit conversion from owner to non-owner? Eternal vigilance is not an answer.

I have to say I'm pretty surprised at how little people here seem to be concerned with type-safety. It is a repeated aim of "modern" C++.

Comment: IMO the implicit conversion should only work for `&` and `const &`, but not `&&`.

Comment: Views are not designed for ownership.

Comment: @MooingDuck If it works for `const &` it'll work for `&&`.

Comment: I agree it isn't ideal, but C++ programmers already need to thing about ownership whenever they use references; apparently now they'll need to remember to treat `_view` the same way they treat `&`.

Comment: @DanielH isn't it possible to explicitly overload those separately?

Comment: @monkey0506 You're right; I forgot you could explicitly declare it `=delete`; unless you do that it'll fall back on the `const&` constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, and that is why there should only be an explicit conversion. An **implicit** conversion from an owning type to non-owning bad design IMO.

Comment: @user9816683 : Like the implicit binding of a reference to an object that's always been in the language? How is this worse again..?

Comment: @ildjam Well this hasn't always been in the language. It's new and therefore is an opportunity to improve, Yet it is contrary to stated goals of "modern" C++, specifically type-safety in this case. New features should aim higher than merely not being worse than existing ones.

Comment: Oh well I guess this is just another default they got wrong.

Comment: The Standards Committee could have effectively gotten the best of both by simply overloading `operator std::string_view() const &&` (`=delete` would be a good candidate). The implicit conversion would still work for non-temporary objects, but you wouldn't end up constructing a `string_view` to an object that is about to be destroyed after the constructor finishes.

Comment: @monkey0506 : `foo(bar())` given `void foo(string_view)` and `string bar()` wouldn't compile, and that would surely cause complaints regarding C++'s (lack of) ergonomics. :-]

Comment: @user9816683: You cannot change the nature of a question so radically. You originally asked a question about why the standard is the way it is. You can't turn that into a question about what to do *because* of what the standard says. But both questions are opinion-based.

Comment: Does your code base have references?  String views are references; same care need be taken.  I have written shared ownership std string likes with shared ownership views into it, but that isn't cheap with the reference counting contention you get.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The point is not about dealing with references. It is about surprising implicit conversions.

Comment: @ildjarn in the comments on einpoklum's answer below it's pointed out to me quite clearly that I misunderstood the lifetime of temporaries in cases like these. You are correct, and my comment is totally wrong.

Comment: @monkey0506 : I saw, no worries. :-] BTW see for the proper standardese, in case you're the pedantic type (as many posting to this tag are): http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6

Comment: @user replace string view with string reference.  The same implicit lifetime issues exist.  If you have a type Foo that stores a string const ref and takes it by construction, your code compiles and the reference dangles as well.

Comment: FWIW Titus Winters agrees there is a problem :P http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0922r0.pdf

Comment: also above pdf has some reasoning why string_view is so horrible(it enables some use cases)

Answer (score 3):

> Please tell me that there are better reasons for an implicit conversion from `basic_string` to `basic_string_view`.

Well, we want to:

1. be able write functions working on `string_view`s rather than `string`s, so as not to constrain the caller regarding how the string data is stored / who owns it - and not having to write variants of these functions for `string`s, `char *`'s etc.
2. Be able to easily pass `string`s to these functions

so we need the implicit conversion.

Comment: question, so can we safely say that `string_view` is somewhat similar to a container?

Comment: 1. What prevents writing template functions that can operator on string and string_view? AFAICT string_view's abstraction should be a subset of string's.

Comment: 2. I still don't see how this isn't just prioritizing the small convenience of an implicit instead of explicit cast in favor of robust semantics WRT ownership.

Comment: @user9816683: "*I still don't see how this isn't just prioritizing...*" Who says it isn't? Neither side is 100% wrong; each one has a point. But they're arguing from a separate set of *values*. You seem to value safety above all other considerations. Others value usability and performance. The fact that your first thought to making the comparison example work was to convert the `string_view` into a `string` shows that performance is *not* your primary value here.

Comment: @NicolBolas "performance" here meaning the efficacy of the end-user not having to use `static_cast`, but safety could have been provided with the same usability and performance by providing (or rather, deleting) a `&&` overload. The conversion from `string&&` to `string_view` is never a valid construct.

Comment: @monkey0506: Nonsense. `void func(string_view sv); string func2(); func(func2());` That's perfectly valid. Deleting the && conversion would make this perfectly valid code not compile.

Comment: @NicolBolas but is the lifetime of the `string&&` guaranteed until the end of `func`? Perhaps my understanding is wrong, but I thought that the lifetime of the returned object would end as soon as `sv` was constructed.

Comment: @monkey0506 the lifetime of a temporary is guaranteed up to the end of the expression that uses the temporary. That means in `func(func2());`, the `string` is guaranteed to be valid up to the `;` ie until `func()` exits, not just to when `sv` is constructed.

Comment: I take back what I said about it not being valid then, because I was of the understanding that the lifetime of the temporary would only be extended through `string const&` or `string&&` function parameters, and not through a conversion such as this.

Comment: @monkey0506 your understanding of the lifetime management of temporaries is wrong in this case. You have some studying to do.

Comment: @NicolBolas You've missed the point. The example is about how someone might not realize they're supposed to be using a string_view. The implicit vs expilcit conversion has nothing to do with performance. My argument is about usability vs. safety. And, I argue that having to do an explicit conversion is much much less important than clear semantics about ownership.

Comment: @user9816683: And you can argue that all you like. But it is still an argument, not a fact. Some will agree with you, others will not. But your argument based on your values won't make the committee's decision *wrong* in some objective sense, only wrong relative to your value system. But the question you asked was about why it was done. It was done because the committee valued usability above safety in this case. That's the answer. You may not believe it to be sufficient or to warrant the safety costs. But that remains the answer nevertheless.

Comment: @user9816683 : Putting a bandaid on some library APIs when references are a thing is.. silly, at best (IMO). This is C++ – one _always_ has to be careful and conscious regarding ownership.

Comment: @NicolBolas It looks like you're trying to invent a false dichotomy between safety and performance.

Comment: @ildjarn This isn't a bandaid. It's a new feature.

Comment: @user9816683 : His comment doesn't mention the word 'performance', but rather 'usability'. It looks like you're grasping at straws for reasons to discredit anyone presenting alternative opinions. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn You're reading the wrong comment. He does mention performance.

Comment: Oh, you were replying to the comment from over half an hour ago, that you had already replied to, a second time? Not the one 4 minutes before your comment? Silly me for assuming this conversation was chronological... >_>

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have previously read that constructors specifically introduce an exception to the meaning of "full expression", but I now understand that this was completely incorrect.