# How to implicitly convert `basic_string` to deduced `basic_string_view` template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am writing a generic algorithm that can work with strings or string segments of any character type -- and so I have decided to work with `std::basic_string_view` with deduced template arguments for `CharT` and `Traits`. However, I have quickly discovered that this doesn't allow for passing `std::basic_string` objects in, since the conversion operators are unable to contribute to the template deduction -- and so I am looking for a viable workaround.

At its core, I have a functor object that accepts some kind of `basic_string_view` with deduced template arguments for `CharT` and `Traits`:

```cpp
struct my_algorithm {
  template <typename CharT, typename Traits>
  auto operator()(std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits> sv) -> void;
};
```

I would like to be able to pass this function an instantiation of *some*  `std::basic_string` without having to explicitly specify the template parameters to the function:

```cpp
auto s = std::basic_string<char>{"hello world"}; // some basic_string, doesn't have to be '<char>'

my_algorithm{}(s); // fails to compile
```

The error this generates due to being unable to deduce the template overload is:

```
<source>: In function 'void test()':
<source>:13:19: error: no match for call to '(my_algorithm) (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'
   13 |     my_algorithm{}(s);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:7:8: note: candidate: 'template<class CharT, class Traits> void my_algorithm::operator()(std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)'
    7 |   auto operator()(std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits> sv) -> void{}
      |        ^~~~~~~~
<source>:7:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:19: note:   'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>'
   13 |     my_algorithm{}(s);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ph9qqd4M1)</kbd>

Is it possible to work around this in-practice? I'm ideally looking for behavior similar to how this would be if it were [statically defined](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y6PPx6Khj), which works.

I can think of a couple potential workarounds, but each with substantial drawbacks:

- Produce a series of overloads for `my_algorithm::operator()(...)` for each string type I want to support (`basic_string`, `const CharT*`, etc). This unfortunately does not scale well, since my codebase has more than one "string" type with conversions to `string_view`. Also the real code involves 2 string arguments, so this increases overloads exponentially.
- Always manually convert `std::basic_string` to `std::basic_string_view` first before calling `accept` (manual effort on the caller's part):

  ```cpp
  my_algorithm{}(std::string_view{s});
  ```

**Is there any way to achieve this conversion without an exhaustive overload, and without the user being required to explicitly create a view?**

---

**Note:** I have found two other questions asking something that *sounds* similar, but neither of them actually refer to deduced template types.

1. [implicitly convert string to string_view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166194)
2. [basic_string to basic_string_view Implicit Conversion… ughhh why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458119)

Comment: No, you can't. Template deduction does not work in a such way. Use overloads. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: @S.M. I'm aware the deduction doesn't actually work this way -- I outright acknowledge the conversion being the problem, and that I am looking for an alternative workaround _of some sort_.

Comment: Currently the best solution I can consider would be to use heavy amounts of type-traits and a template-argument rather than a deduced argument. At least with this I can detect `value_type` and `traits_type`, and detect whether a conversion to `basic_string_view<char_type, traits_type>` is viable. It'd be complicated, but it'd at least solve the problem effectively.

Comment: The overload is an effective and well readable solution.

Comment: @S.M. I already covered this in the question; perhaps you missed that part? The actual problem involves several different string types (not just `std::string`), and with multiple string arguments -- which increases the number of overloads exponentially.

Comment: Why exponentially? You call `operator()(std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>` from all overloads, this is linear.

Comment: @S.M. I have stated this in the potential workarounds section of the question that this is a minimal reproducible example; the actual problem involves *multiple arguments* as in (e.g. `operator()(std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>, std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>)`). That is *not* linear, because now there are combinations involved. This is becoming extended discussion at this point, and is not constructive as it is not leading to an adequate solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing is to make it a more general template

```
struct my_algorithm {
  template <typename StringView>
  auto operator()(StringView&& sv) -> void {
      using Traits = typename std::remove_cvref_t<StringView>::traits_type;
      using CharT = typename std::remove_cvref_t<StringView>::value_type;
      /* ... */
  }
};
```

If you have other overloads, you will want to SFINAE that, which will be easier in C++20 with concepts

```
template <typename T>
concept stringlike = requires { 
  typename std::remove_cvref_t<T>::traits_type;
  typename std::remove_cvref_t<T>::value_type;
}

struct my_algorithm {
  template <stringlike StringView>
  auto operator()(StringView&& sv) -> void {
      using Traits = typename std::remove_cvref_t<StringView>::traits_type;
      using CharT = typename std::remove_cvref_t<StringView>::value_type;
      /* ... */
  }
};
```

Comment: This is basically the solution I was thinking to go for in the end (as mentioned in the comments) -- thanks for the answer! Also unfortunately I'm still using C++17 so I don't have access to `concept`s for this project; but I _can_ at least thankfully convert this to using the detected-idiom instead with `enable_if`

Comment: Yes, for this particular case you might be able to put `std::void_t<typename std::remove_cvref_t<StringView>::traits_type, typename std::remove_cvref_t<StringView>::value_type>` somewhere appropriate